# how to get rid of unintended space between letters

Tags: code-review

I am facing a terrible problem with `Mathematica`. I have a very large system of equations to solve. The code works just fine, but when I exit Mathematica and then recall the same `code`, `Mathematica` "randomly" inserts space between some letters or between some numbers or both. Therefore, the code stops working, and I spend a lot of time to find where the spaces were inserted. An example of the problem is:

```
eq1 = var1   + 3*var3 == 56;
eq2 = 4*var2 + 25*var3 == 7;
```

When `Mathematica` recalls the above two equations, the following occurs:

```
e q1 = var1    + 3*var 3 == 5 6;
eq 2 = 4*var 2 + 2 5*var 3 == 7;
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: `Mathematica "randomly" inserts space between some letters or between some numbers or both` this does not sound right. There is something wrong with your set up. Mathematica does strange things sometimes, but I never saw it insert spaces randomly into the code. Are you using Input cell or Code cell? Standard style sheet? what version, etc.. more information is needed. Try to reset Mathematia  to its initial state and see if this fixes things.

Comment: You might have a corrupted notebook. I have had problems in which what I reloaded was different from what I saved. I suggest creating a new notebook and copying what can be saved.

Comment: @Nasser: I use input cells for the code and text cells for writing notes. The code is placed in input cells using `consolas` font. I do not use `code` cells. My Mathematica version is 11.3. What do you mean with `reseting it to initial state`?

Comment: @mikado:  I created a new notebook, but when copying the code from the original notebook into the new one, the font non-uniformly changes. I cannot set the font chosen as a default. Now I have more troubles.